# Extjs4 Creating a mixin

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Im trying to create a mixing for `Ext.grid.Panel` components. This is how I have attempted to do it:

```
Ext.define('myMixin', {
    myFunc:function(){
        console.log('completed!');
    }
});

Ext.grid.Panel.mixin('newmixin','myMixin');
```

The result of this is a mixin has been added to grid components, but the value is `undefined`. Hopefully I have missed something simple, but some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, but im still not 100% sure of the reason. If somebody can explain im more than happy to mark them as the answer.

I did the following:

```
Ext.grid.Panel.mixin('newmixin',Ext.define('myMixin', {
    myFunc:function(){
        console.log('completed!');
    }
}));
```

Comment: I think the reason is that in your original code, you were attempt to reference myMixin using the string 'myMixin': Ext.grid.Panel.mixin('newmixin','myMixin');  But you only *define* a class definition using a string such as 'myMixin' -- after it's defined you refer to its object reference: myMixin (without the quotes)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that Ext.define completes asynchronously.  I don't know what Ext.grid.Panel.mixin is, as this does not exist in ExtJS 4.0.1, but you might try adding the mixin within the callback parameter of Ext.define:

```
Ext.define('myMixin', {
    myFunc:function(){
        console.log('completed!');
    }
}, function() {
    Ext.grid.Panel.mixin('newmixin','myMixin');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add your mixin declaratively?

```
Ext.define('Path.to.MyMixin', {
    someFunc: function () {return 0;}
});
```

And then, in your grid:

```
Ext.define('Path.to.MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    mixins: ['Path.to.MyMixin'],
    ...
});
```